# When to bump SONAME in shared libraries installing templates?

Tags: c++, templates, shared-libraries

I am writing a shared library which will install a template header as well. Considering the specific fact that the template will be instantiated by the caller rather than the library itself, when should I bump SONAME for changes in the template code?

For regular C/C++ code I bump SONAME whenever the binary compatibility breaks. But for templates, I'm starting to think bumping it everytime *anything* in the template changes so that the changes would be propagated.

Comment: I think I wouldn't bump SONAMES when only templates cange. Proof: If it would be all templates, there would only be headers, and there wouldn't be any SONAME at all!

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: I was specifically considering adding even a dummy library reference to enforce the SONAME.